# Flatten result of nested relationship in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel application with following models

```
Location (hasOne: Device)  : [id, device_id, lat, lng] 
Device (hasMany: Location) : [id, name]
```

I need to get the lates location for given devices. Say I have an array of device ids.

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I am trying to make an api which suppose to give a flat response for a request. Apparently the response should look like this.

```
[
    {
    "device_id": "1",
    "name": "A",
    "lat":"8.311",
    "lng":"11.1111"
    },
    {
    "device_id": "2",
    "name": "B",
    "lat":"8.1111",
    "lng":"88.1111"
    },
    {
    "device_id": "3",
    "name": "C",
    "lat":"5.1111",
    "lng":"25.1111"
    }
]
```

I have tried many methods to find an efficient solution to get the correct answer. So far the best solution I can think of is to directly fetch the latest location from the `Location` table with the `device_id`s. So I tried this.

```
Location::whereIn('device_id', [1, 2, 3])->get()
```

Which gives all the location entries for the given devices. But I want only the latest location entry for each device. So I tried this.

```
Location::whereIn('device_id', [1, 2])->latest()->first()->get()
```

Which apparently giving me more than one location for each device. I am not sure how I can tackle this.

```
>>> Location::whereIn('device_id', [1, 2])->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2883
     all: [
       App\Location {#2895
         id: 1,
         device_id: 1,
         lat: "39",
         lng: "53",
         extras: "JCRskRtaBJ",
         delete_flag: 0,
         created_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
         updated_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
       },
       App\Location {#2903
         id: 3,
         device_id: 1,
         lat: "73",
         lng: "23",
         extras: "0cOy8rne9S",
         delete_flag: 0,
         created_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
         updated_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
       },
       App\Location {#2894
         id: 5,
         device_id: 2,
         lat: "55",
         lng: "28",
         extras: "rT18VZxA7i",
         delete_flag: 0,
         created_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
         updated_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
       },
       App\Location {#2885
         id: 7,
         device_id: 1,
         lat: "58",
         lng: "74",
         extras: "TAbM4x53iH",
         delete_flag: 0,
         created_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
         updated_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
       },
       App\Location {#2900
         id: 8,
         device_id: 1,
         lat: "47",
         lng: "7",
         extras: "yhr4sbUs2R",
         delete_flag: 0,
         created_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
         updated_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
       },
       App\Location {#2882
         id: 9,
         device_id: 2,
         lat: "27",
         lng: "60",
         extras: "NqRPvaqosG",
         delete_flag: 0,
         created_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
         updated_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
       },
       App\Location {#2915
         id: 10,
         device_id: 1,
         lat: "35",
         lng: "37",
         extras: "6e7yHT4qP3",
         delete_flag: 0,
         created_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
         updated_at: "2018-07-25 12:11:21",
       },
     ],
   }
```

I am looking for a query which returns just the `lat`, `lng` from the location class and append it as a property so that I can have a flat json response. Is it anyway possible to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want using the [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) :

First create a new relation in the `Device` model, even if `hasMany` is the real relation between them you can use `hasOne` alongside with `latest()` to get the last location :

```
public function lastLocation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Location')->latest();
}
```

Then you have to create a Device resource :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Device extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'device_id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'lat' => $this->lastLocation->lat,
            'lng' => $this->lastLocation->lng,
        ];
    }
}
```

Finally in the controller you can do this :

```
use App\Device;
use App\Http\Resources\Device as DeviceResource;

function YourMethod() {
    $devices = Device::with('lastLocation')
                       ->whereIn([1, 2, 3])
                       ->get();
    return DeviceResource::collection($devices);
}
```

One more thing as mentioned in the doc :

> By default, your outer-most resource is wrapped in a data key when the
>   resource response is converted to JSON. So, for example, a typical
>   resource collection response looks like the following:
>
> ```
> {
>     "data": [
>         {
>             "id": 1,
>             "name": "Eladio Schroeder Sr.",
>             "email": "therese28@example.com",
>         },
>         {
>             "id": 2,
>             "name": "Liliana Mayert",
>             "email": "evandervort@example.com",
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

To remove the data wrapper :

> If you would like to disable the wrapping of the outer-most resource,
>   you may use the withoutWrapping method on the base resource class.
>   Typically, you should call this method from your AppServiceProvider or
>   another service provider that is loaded on every request to your
>   application :
>
> ```
> public function boot()
> {
>     Resource::withoutWrapping();
> }
> ```

Comment: Finally, this one worked for me with little tweaks. On the resource I had to call  ``$this->lastLocation()->first()->get()->lat``. Any Idea why?

Comment: There is a trick that you can use, you can use hasOne instead of hasMany to get exactly the last location check the updated answer :)

Comment: Nice answer but, personnaly, i search for a solution that allow me to do something like: return array_merge([...], new LocationResource($this->lastLocation)).
In order to not have to copy all nested attributes since i use parent::toArray() to generate $this array.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use `groupBy` with `latest`. Then pass only the columns you want to `get`. Then return a response based on the result set, and a status code based on the result.

```
$locations = Location::whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->latest() // like distinct, but is based on the primary key
    ->groupBy('device_id') // this is the piece you were missing with latest
    ->select('device_id', 'lat', 'lng') // only columns you want
    ->get();

return response()->json($location ? $location->toJson() : [], $location ? 200 : 204);
```

Comment: I very much like to take this approach but I can't seem to get it worked. I am keep on getting the following error. `error in GROUP BY (SQL: select `device_id`, `lat`, `lng` from `locations` where `id` in (1, 2) group by `device_id` order by `created_at` desc)`

Comment: @Fawzan That's odd, try moving the select before the groupBy.